# Re-order table rows so when SELECT they are returned in correct order

Tags: mysql

Just curious about this.

When I need to `SELECT` items and use a complicated `ORDER BY` clause, can I pre-calculate the order and rearrange the rows so that they are always returned in that order?

I can determine the order when I `INSERT` or `UPDATE` anything in the table.

The other alternative would to create an additional `INT` column `ix` and populate that.

Comment: 'I can determine the order when I INSERT or UPDATE anything in the table' - No ,data is stored in unordered sets you would still need an order by but you may be able to simplify the order by with an additional column(s).

Comment: I think you'll need to illustrate what you mean. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query